# How to extend 'should' library

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, mocha.js, should.js

I would like o introduce to should assert library, working for tests of my node.js app,  my additional functions.

Something like in this **pseudocode**

```
should      = require "should"

myExists = (obj, msg) ->
  # my special exist logic

containSomething = (obj, msg) ->
  # my special assert logic

should.myExists = myExists
should.containSomething = containSomething


describe.only "`my extra `", ->
   it 'should be working', (done) ->
     obj = {}
     obj.should.myExists  
     obj.should.not.myExists  
     obj.should.containSomething {cool:obj}
     obj.should.not.containSomething {cool:obj}
     done()
```

Any suggestions how to do that in practice?

Comment: have you tried implementing it? What happened when you did?

Comment: @ben336 it's not working. myExist not exist in object should.

Comment: Looks like you have a typo.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
should.myExits = myExists
```

should probably be

```
should.myExist = myExists
```

Comment: this is not about typo problem ( I put a pseudo code) but it's about extending Object with new methods.